# (Django) define `__str__` in a model with attributes of other model not yet defined

Tags: python, django

For Django 1.9, I implemented two simple models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        # TO IMPLEMENT: Get the name of newest model B associated with A

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    to_a = models.ForeignKey(A)

    def __str__(self):
        return name
```

Model `A` is for a group of model `B` (by ForeignKey `to_a`.)

I want to make `__str__` of model `A` to be the `name` of `B` which has newest `date` among those who are related to given `A` with `to_a`.

For example, if we have two `A : [A1, A2]` and three `B : [("1", 2014-01-01, A1), ("2", 2015-01-01, A2), ("3", 2015-12-19, A1)]`, then `A2.__str__()` should return `"3"`.

How can I implement `A.__str__`?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all that you define `B` farther down in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will help you

```
self.b_set.last().name
```